# Git GUI when on a remote server

Tags: git, user-interface

I have a Git repository on a remote server, but how do I get a GUI on my local machine?

I don't want to have ANY of the files on my local machine, just a GUI to interact with the remote server.

Platform: Windows

**EDIT**
Just to clarify, I want a FTP-like program with visual git commands

Comment: Do you want to _see_ repository or to _work_ with it?

Comment: I want to work with the files

Comment: Is installing something like gitweb out of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install xming (x server) and run git guy over ssh with X11forwarding?

Comment: Thanks, performance is not great but seems to be the only solution other than installing a GUI on the server. This concept is pretty cool though!

Comment: Can you provide details on how you set this up?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VNC on Windows.

You can use `ssh -X` on Linux and Windows.

Comment: preferred not to. I thought there might be an FTP client like winSCP available with git commands...seems like maybe not